# Onchange function on start_date & end_date in odoo 8

Tags: python, xml, netbeans, odoo-8

Help me.
I would like to know how onchange function works with date fields. Suppose if start_date get changed, then the end_date will change to be the next day. Example, I was change the start_date into 11/11/2016,
then the end_date will change to 11/12/2016

Pls Help, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.
 on python

```
def onchange_start_date(self, cr, uid, ids, start_date, context=None):
        vals = {'end_date': (time.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")+timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}
        return {'value': vals}
```

on xml

```
<field name="start_date" on_change="onchange_start_date(start_date)"/>
```